# Are Metro-style applications necessarily full screen?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Are we only going to be able to create full screen Metro-style applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464920.aspx):

> Metro style apps are **full screen apps** tailored to your users' needs, tailored to the device they run on, tailored for touch interaction, and tailored to the Windows user interface.

Otherwise, as John Gardner points out, your app would not be a Metro-style app: if it exists on the desktop, it is by definition a desktop app.

Comment: Well, that is weak. I guess I'll have to rely on 3rd party Metro Ui like libraries to have Metro, but windowed.

Comment: Not recommended. If you're deploying a desktop app, your users will expect a desktop experience; Metro is not made for that kind of environment (e.g. mouse and keyboard primary, smaller text, etc.)

Comment: I'm just saying. Zune is doing a good job with it's Metro-like application.

Comment: Zune was developed before Windows 8 was announced. I'm sure the version for Windows 8 will be fully integrated into the system, and similarly, any non-Metro apps Microsoft releases for Windows 8 will embrace the desktop paradigm.

Comment: Didn't know that. I guess i'll just stick with normal WPF application and just use Metro for my WP7 version of my application.

Comment: Metro Style app is resizable... see **snap feature** on msdn

Comment: @saleh That is not what resizable means. It's more that Metro style apps have two modes than that they can be resized.

Comment: @domenic yeah resizable in two modes

Comment: @saleh As I said, that is not what resizable means.

Answer (score 6):

But that's kindof the point of Metro.

You don't always have fullscreen either, because depending on screen size, you can have 2 applications visible.

If you want to use the desktop, you fall back into the standard windows desktop and use standard desktop applicatoins.

Answer (score 2):

Yes but you can re-size your app by using **Snap Feature**.

I don't know exactly what are your requirements but better look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465371.aspx) and this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nODsV71yedA)